# Jquery datepicker - How to highlight current date but not fill in the input box

Tags: jquery

I have an input box for the user to input a purchase date for an item. It works perfectly except it shows today's date in the input box. I don't want this if there's no default value (nothing in DB). I only want the date to be highlighted when the calendar pops up.

```
<input name="purchase_date" value="<?php echo set_value('purchase_date', $purchase_date);?>" type="text" class="span2 datepicker">
```

Here's the JS.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker().datepicker('setDate', 'today');
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery UI datepicker widget highlights the current day by default.

It's showing today's date in the textbox because you're setting the value with:

```
.datepicker('setDate','today');
```

Comment: It could be the JS that I'm using. I purchased a theme from themeforest and the author could be overriding it somehow. This demo page from Jquery shows it can be done. http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: And here's the theme. http://www.malijuthemeshop.com/live_previews/mooncake/simple/ui_components.html

Comment: Yeah, it looks like they are overriding the `ui-state-highlight` class that the datepicker uses for the current date.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am very late, but it's never late for easy solutions.

You can accomplish your requirement by this one line of code:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    todayHighlight: true,
    ...
})
```

Taken from: https://github.com/jquery-ui-bootstrap/jquery-ui-bootstrap/issues/170#issuecomment-77184005

Hope this helps.